# Unspecified error during copy process

Tags: hyper-v

has anyone made experience with a unspecified error during copy big (2-3GB) files to the local hyper-v machine? My machine has in any case enough memory and space. The error comes quite suddenly during the copy process. Where can I get specific error details? There is nothing in my Windows Event logger :-/

Best regards

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. I had to use 7-zip to split the large files and copy them in smaller bits and then extract the file on the server.

Comment: @Patrik Could you please provide the OS you are dealing with. I get this message on Server 2012 R2 when starting a second copy job.

Answer (score 14):

Copying files larger than 2 GB over a Remote Desktop Services or a Terminal Services session through Clipboard Redirection (copy and paste) is not supported. Please check
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2258090

Comment: Excerpt from your link [using the RDP client 6.0 or a later version, the file is not copied. And, you **do not receive an error message**]. So this is not the case here.

Comment: Yes. Correct! To overcome this problem simply share the directory containing the big file (size > 2 GB) like a network share inside your VM. From your host machine browse to the network share path of the VM where you file is present. Now you can copy it. The 2 GB limit is a problem only when you try doing it through MSTSC terminal.

Comment: I observe the same "Unspecified error" when copying a 872 MB file from a VMConnect enhanced session (guest Windows 8.1, host Windows 10). Copying via a shared folder works fine.

Comment: use ftp server to dowload file

Comment: The 2GB limit seems to be gone, however this error can be caused by trying to use the clipboard while the copy operation is in process (which is more easy to trigger with larger files)

Answer (score 8):

RDP transfers files through your clipboard. Copying something while the transfer is taking place (which is particularly easy in a large file transfer, because you probably want to do something else as it is happening, and copying things is a very common operation) fails the entire thing with an unspecified error.

If it's possible to you, consider using drive redirection, as it is *much* faster and resilient to this.

Comment: Here's some info on the drive redirection mentioned above: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770631(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It happens for me when I try to copy some other text or file when a large file is being copied over Remote desktop services whereas in local machine, it allows parallel copy.

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me:

1. Log into the Remote Desktop.
2. Browse to your computer over the network.
3. Copy file to the Remote Desktop.